# How to parse json second level objects?

Tags: ruby, json, parsing

I have following json response, here I1 is the main object and I1-1, I1-2 are the sub objects

```
{ 
 "I1": "Main Object 1", 
 "I1-1": "Sub Object 1", 
 "I1-2": "Sub Object 2", 
 "I2": "Main Object 2", 
 "I2-1": "Sub Object 1", 
 "I2-2": "Sub Object 2", 
 "I3": "Main Object 3", 
 "I3-1": "Sub Object 1", 
 "I3-2": "Sub Object 2" 
}
```

How do I parse the above response to filter main_objects and sub_objects in ruby?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
require 'json'

data = JSON.parse('{
 "I1": "Main Object 1",
 "I1-1": "Sub Object 1",
 "I1-2": "Sub Object 2",
 "I2": "Main Object 2",
 "I2-1": "Sub Object 1",
 "I2-2": "Sub Object 2",
 "I3": "Main Object 3",
 "I3-1": "Sub Object 1",
 "I3-2": "Sub Object 2"
}')

main_objects = data.select { |k, _| k =~ /\AI\d+\z/ }
sub_objects  = data.select { |k, _| k =~ /\AI\d+\-\d+\z/ }

p main_objects # => {"I1"=>"Main Object 1", "I2"=>"Main Object 2", "I3"=>"Main Object 3"}
p sub_objects # => {"I1-1"=>"Sub Object 1", "I1-2"=>"Sub Object 2", "I2-1"=>"Sub Object 1", "I2-2"=>"Sub Object 2", "I3-1"=>"Sub Object 1", "I3-2"=>"Sub Object 2"}
```